# Obtaining elements from javascript pop up window using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, html, web, htmlunit

The problem: When I click on an image of a product on a website, a window pops up above the website page and displays the product's description. It also contains a form. I want to know how to get this form and the text description. Is this possible using HtmlUnit?

Thank you for any support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But different developers have different approach.

1. I might simply figure out the request being sent on click.
2. It may be possible, that there's no request being sent, instead the content present in a div (or similar element) is just being rendered in the form of a popup, in which case you have to find out the actual code in the source.
3. Htmlunit can handle only native javascript popup windows. According to your question, that's not a native dialog, so you can simply issue .click() on that htmlelement and then get the required using xPath in javascript enabled mode.

Regards
Nitin

Comment: if that solved your problem, please consider accepting it as a solution.